# How can I add a new column based on the conditions from other tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

How can I add a new column named “entry_page” to column B? The values of the new column “entry_page” should be “page_location” that has the earliest datetime value from column A by session ID.

I appreciate your help!

**column names of table A** 
EVENT_AT (daytime), 
EXT_GA_SESSION_ID (session ID),
EXT_STREAM_ID (product ID), 
EXT_USER_PSEUDO_ID (user ID), 
PAGE_LOCATION (url address)

**column names of table B** 
EXT_GA_SESSION_ID,
EXT_STREAM_ID,
EXT_USER_PSEUDO_ID,
DEVICE_CATEGORY,
DEVICE_OPERATING_SYSTEM, 
GEO_COUNTRY, 
GEO_REGION

I tried to get the first value of "PAGE_LOCATION" by "EXT_GA_SESSION_ID", but it gave me the error and I don't know where to fix. Below is the query I tried.

```
SELECT B.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, A.PAGE_LOCATION FROM B
id in (SELECT MIN(id) FROM B GROUP BY EXT_GA_SESSION_ID);
```

Comment: You need to JOIN the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the combination `EVENT_AT` and `PAGE_LOCATION` is unique, we can proceed as follows:

To begin, use `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` to get the oldest *EVENT_AT*:

```
SELECT EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, min(EVENT_AT) as min_event_at
FROM A
GROUP BY EXT_GA_SESSION_ID
```

Then will join this dataset with TABLE A to get the related the oldest `PAGE_LOCATION`

```
SELECT A.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, A.PAGE_LOCATION
FROM A
JOIN (
  SELECT EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, min(EVENT_AT) as min_event_at
  FROM A
  GROUP BY EXT_GA_SESSION_ID
) AS S on S.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID = A.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID and S.min_event_at = A.EVENT_AT
```

Last step is to join this query with table B to get the expected data :

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, T.PAGE_LOCATION as "entry_page"
FROM B
JOIN (
  SELECT A.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, A.PAGE_LOCATION
  FROM A
  JOIN (
    SELECT EXT_GA_SESSION_ID, min(EVENT_AT) as min_event_at
    FROM A
    GROUP BY EXT_GA_SESSION_ID
  ) AS S on S.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID = A.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID and S.min_event_at = A.EVENT_AT
) as T on T.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID = B.EXT_GA_SESSION_ID
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help @SelVazi! I have a question about the last block of code. Can I know where did you get "T" from "T.PAGE_LOCATION"? I believe you code you suggested did not create table T? or you're creating table T in the last code?

Comment: T is only an alias of the dataset that is required to join the second subquery with table B; no table have been created